# observableArray and selected value from autocomplate

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-jqautocomplete

I didn't work with knockoutjs during last couple years, I forgotten some basic stuff about mapping,

I have an array that should keep list of values (JSON) that selected from autocomplete 
I have created next code:

```
 define(['jquery', 'knockout', 'koAutocomplete', 'mapBase','app/obj/routePoint'],
    function ($, ko, koAutocomplete, mapBase, routePoint) {
    return function routeBuilder() {
        var self = this;
        mapBase.initMap();
        self.rootPoints = ko.observableArray([new routePoint()]);
        self.addNewPoint = function () {
            self.rootPoints.push(new routePoint());
        };
        self.removePoint = function () {
            self.rootPoints.remove(this);
        };
        self.getOptions = function(searchTerm, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/api/Geocoder",
                data: {
                    query: searchTerm
                },
            }).done(function (results) {                
                callback(mapBase.convertToAutoComplate(results));
            });
        }
    };
});

// Main viewmodel class
define(['knockout'],
    function (ko) {

        return function routePoint(label, locationId) {
            var self = this;     
            self.label = label;
            self.locationId = locationId;
            self.selectedData = ko.observable();
    };
});

<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: rootPoints, as: 'point' } ">
    <li>
        Name at position <span data-bind="text: $index"> </span>:
        <input placeholder="Start Type Name" 
               data-bind="jqAuto: { 
               value: $data.selectedData().label, 
               valueProp: '$data, 
               source: $parent.getOptions, 
               dataValue: $data,
               inputProp: 'label', 
               labelProp: 'label', 
               options: { minLength: 3 } }" />
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removePoint">Remove</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

as a result I see my selection, at ui but rootPoints  array continence empty values.
How to map selected object to specific array index ?

Comment: What is mapBase.convertToAutoComplate returning?

Comment: @JasonSpake routePoint object list

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in that function does it get hit?

Comment: yes, I see a list of option, but how to map it to item in array (I mean after selection I expected to have selected  routePoint at item list rootPoints)

Comment: I see now. I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the jqAutocomplete library. From the [documentation](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-jqAutocomplete):

> **dataValue** - If specified, this observable will be populated with the
>   currently selected data item. This option will allow you to populate
>   value with the valueProp and have access to the selected object at the
>   same time through dataValue.

So to access the selected option you first need an observable property to store it, and then you pass that observable to the dataValue binding. I think you need to make a new observable on the parent view-model and change your binding option to use that.

```
return function routeBuilder() {
    var self = this;
    mapBase.initMap();
    self.rootPoints = ko.observableArray([new routePoint()]);
    self.selectedPoint = ko.observable();
...       

<input placeholder="Start Type Name" 
       data-bind="jqAuto: { 
           source: $parent.getOptions,
           dataValue: $parent.selectedPoint,
...
```

Comment: yes, you are right but I need to have  self.selectedData at rootPoints points. I have upto N elements in array, and each should  be selected. as you can see I have foreach at view

Comment: I didn't realize that property was used for something else. How about now? New observable called selectedPoint